# Google analytics a/b testing - controlling the redirects

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Normally when I a/b test 3 version of my landing page, I set the experiment as follows:

1) www.xxx.com

2) www.xxx.com?version=new1

3) www.xxx.com?version=new2

Thus I have 3 versions where the original is the first one

But now, I need an advanced feature which I couldn't find how to do so by googling.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

if google redirects the user to version (2) or version (3) && some parameter I have on the page is false - I would like it to be redirected to the version (1).

How can I make that happen ?

Comment: This questions isn't really programing related you might want to try the G+ community https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537

Comment: Wouldn't this wreck your test (since traffic to the variations would be unevenly distributed) ?

Comment: If you control when Googles experiment js-code is put on the page you could choose not to put it there when the parameter is false. (I assume the parameter is false in the default page as well in those cases).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my needs which is called Content Experiment

```
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side
```